# What is the use of "push %ebp; movl %esp, %ebp" generated by GCC for x86?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

What effect these two instructions cause in the assembly code generated by gcc for x86 machines:

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
```

Answer (score 60):

unwind's explanation is the literal truth (one minor directional error notwithstanding), but doesn't explain why.

`%ebp` is the "base pointer" for your stack frame.  It's the pointer used by the C runtime to access local variables and parameters on the stack.  Here's some typical function prologue code generated by GCC (g++ to be precise)  First the C++ source.

```
// junk.c++
int addtwo(int a)
{
    int x = 2;

    return a + x;
}
```

This generates the following assembler.

```
.file   "junk.c++"
    .text
.globl _Z6addtwoi
    .type   _Z6addtwoi, @function
_Z6addtwoi:
.LFB2:
    pushl   %ebp
.LCFI0:
    movl    %esp, %ebp
.LCFI1:
    subl    $16, %esp
.LCFI2:
    movl    $2, -4(%ebp)
    movl    -4(%ebp), %edx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    leave
    ret
.LFE2:
    .size   _Z6addtwoi, .-_Z6addtwoi
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Now to explain that prologue code (all the stuff before `.LCFI2:`), first:

1. `pushl %ebp` stores the stack frame of the *calling* function on the stack.
2. `movl %esp, %ebp` takes the current stack pointer and uses it as the frame for the *called* function.
3. `subl $16, %esp` leaves room for local variables.

Now your function is ready for business.  Any references with a negative offset from the `%ebp%` register are your local variables (`x` in this example).  Any references with a positive offset from the `%ebp%` register are your parameters passed in.

The final point of interest is the `leave` instruction which is an x86 assembler instruction which does the work of restoring the calling function's stack frame.  This is usually optimized away in to the faster `move %ebp %esp` and `pop %ebp%` sequence in C code.  For illustrative purposes, however, I didn't compile with any optimizations on at all.

Comment: To add to this answer, there are various calling conventions that govern the order in which the input parameters are pushed onto the stack and also who would clean up after the function is done.

Answer (score 9):

It's typical code that you see at the beginning of a function.

It saves the contents of the EBP register on the stack, and then stores the content of the current stack pointer in EBP.

The stack is used during a function call to store local arguments. But in the function, the stack pointer may change because values are stored on the stack.

If you save the original value of the stack, you can refer to the stored arguments via the EBP register, while you can still use (add values to) the stack.

At the end of the function you will probably see the command

```
pop %ebp   ; restore original value 
ret        ; return
```

Comment: `movl %ebp,%esp / popl %ebp / ret`-->First restore `ESP`, *then* pop `EBP`

Answer (score 8):

```
push %ebp
```

This will push the 32 bit (extended) base pointer register on the stack, i.e. the stack pointer (%esp) is subtracted by four, then the value of %ebp is copied to the location that the stack pointer points to.

```
movl %esp, %ebp
```

This copies the stack pointer register to the base pointer register.

The purpose of copying the stack pointer to the base pointer is to create a stack frame, i.e. an area on the stack where a subroutine can store local data. The code in the subroutine would use the base pointer to reference the data.

Comment: Last sentence wasnt described before. Thanks for that! Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of what is known as the [function prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue).

It saves the current base pointer that is going to be retrieved when the function ends and sets the new ebp to the beginning of the new frame.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that it is important to note that often after 
`push %ebp` and 
`movl %esp, %ebp` 
the assembly will have `push %ebx` or `push %edx`. These are caller saves of the registers `%ebx` and `%edx`.  At the end of the routine call the registers will be restored with their original values.

Also - `%ebx, %esi, %edi` are all callee save registers. So if you want to overwrite them you need to save them first, then restore them.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code sets up the stack for your program.

In x86 stack information is held by two registers.

```
    Base pointer (bp): Holds starting address of the stack
    Stack pointer (sp): Holds the address in which next value will be stored
```

These registers have different names in different modes:

```
                            Base pointer           Stack pointer
    16 bit real mode:       bp                     sp
    32 bit protected mode:  ebp(%ebp)              esp(%esp)
    64 bit mode:            rbp                    rsp
```

When you set up a stack, stack pointer and base pointer gets the same address at the beginning. 

Now to explain your code,

```
    push %ebp
```

This code pushes the current stack address into the stack so that the function can "exit" or "return" properly.

```
    movl %esp, %ebp
```

This code sets up the stack for your function.
For more info, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34544565/assembly-how-to-modify-stack-size/34546238#34546238).
Hope this help!